# Convert string array back to PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, string

In DB TEXT field i have saves string (polygon coordinates), similar to this: `"[[35.408686311173874,-119.14944509590913],[35.408686311173874,-119.14538959587861]]"`

What would be the easiest way to convert this string back to actual PHP array like this: `[[35.408686311173874,-119.14944509590913],[35.408686311173874,-119.14538959587861]]`, when assigning it to a variable?

When I try to `unserialize` I get this error `unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 163 bytes`

At fist, I thought it will be easy, but I still haven't found a solution on how to do that. Any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Simple answer: don't store it like this in the database.

Comment: @Sharman, how would you recommend it to be saved in DB? Depending on polygon complexity, the string/point can be ~100 times longer.

Comment: I would save it in another table. If the relation is 1:N a separate table is required.

Answer (score -2):

As @Nick noted, `json_decode` worked.